# Is there a way to stop docker swarm leave --force from removing the redirection of port of the current containers running

Tags: docker, containers, port, docker-swarm, swarm

I have 2 containers running using the ports 5001 and 5000 of my server. This server can be part of a docker swarm. When I leave the docker swarm using `Docker swarm leave --force` the redirection of my physicals port is gone.

```sh
[98-swarm-hello-world *]$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
dfc9bbc8573b        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   docker-registry_registry-private_1
760cbf6e6b15        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   docker-registry_registry-mirror_1
[98-swarm-hello-world *]$ docker swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (srlmoh6a2nm28biifgv7vpjb1) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-1hws6so0lpikgc1e0ztlhpobj7ejvg0hg4lk0k22wsdss4ntri-7l6eoo7cimlhmpzputbjpo6qt 192.168.65.3:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
[98-swarm-hello-world *]$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
dfc9bbc8573b        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   21 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   docker-registry_registry-private_1
760cbf6e6b15        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   21 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   docker-registry_registry-mirror_1
```

For now the ports are still here but then :

```sh
[98-swarm-hello-world *]$ docker swarm leave --force
Node left the swarm.
[98-swarm-hello-world *]$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
dfc9bbc8573b        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   33 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds                           docker-registry_registry-private_1
760cbf6e6b15        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   33 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds                           docker-registry_registry-mirror_1
```

**EDIT** : My image might have a problem, with another image (created with `docker container run --rm --name nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx`) the ports are still exposed :

```sh
[root@n0300 docker-registry]# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f40e2463eb38        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   6 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   docker-registry_registry-private_1
fbb31476bddf        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   6 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   docker-registry_registry-mirror_1
b3086042d2f5        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       nginx
[root@n0300 docker-registry]# docker swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (s5fpahqg1klnbi2w90pver5ao) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-3b2gv5e1f3x4ez9s3itf5hxnilypvh0g4t4butdhggwqpjsx2n-c4l1o42p4fl9mwy8ktjhl3yzo 172.16.1.44:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

[root@n0300 docker-registry]# docker swarm leave --fore
unknown flag: --fore
See 'docker swarm leave --help'.
[root@n0300 docker-registry]# docker swarm leave --force
Node left the swarm.
[root@n0300 docker-registry]# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
f40e2463eb38        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   22 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds                            docker-registry_registry-private_1
fbb31476bddf        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   22 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds                            docker-registry_registry-mirror_1
b3086042d2f5        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   nginx
```

**EDIT 2 :** My image isn't build, I'm just running a container.
Here's the `compose file`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry-mirror:
    image: registry
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000
    volumes:
      - ./config-mirror-registry.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
  registry-private:
    image: registry
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000
    ports: 
      - "5001:5000"
```

and here the `config file`

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
proxy:
 remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
```

Comment: Weird... I can't reproduce your error. I tried with a nginx image exposing port 80 and when I init/leave a swarm cluster, the port is still exposed. What version of docker are you running ? I'm running docker 18.09.6

Comment: This test was done on docker 18.09.2 but I've had the issue on servers running with docker 18.09.6

Comment: Can you try it with an *independent* image to see if the problem comes from your images or if it is global ? For example `docker container run --rm --name nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx` that's the example i used.

Comment: Good point, my image might have a problem. With your image the ports are still there.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile then ?

Comment: I'll have to ask my team to know if I'm allowed to share the code.

Comment: You don't necesseraly need to share the whole file. Probably just the network configuration.

Comment: Its fine, I have edited my description with it.